# How would I go about hideing a specified value from displaying in an array in a datagrid?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, datagrid

For example, say I have:

```
public var usersOnlineArray:Array = new Array(bob,jim,tim,marry,luke);
```

and when I put that into my datagrid like this:

```
buddylist.dataProvider = new DataProvider(usersOnlineArray);
buddylist.rowCount = buddylist.length;
bldBuddyList(buddylist);
```

How could I, let's say, prevent luke from appearing in the datagrid? Basically make him not appear but technically "still be there" so I can make him reappear later but?

Comment: I assume you are looking for something more than just, create a second array for the those users you want to display, and make that array your dataProvider?

Comment: I was thinking of something more like a filter function or something that i might just not be aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by using ArrayCollection rather than Array since you can make use of data binding this way.

ArrayCollection also has a `filterFunction` property that will allow you to hide things but still keep them in the collection.  The [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) will expand on all of this but the gist is:

Make the ArrayCollection, it just takes plain ole Array in the constructor.

`public var usersArr:Array = [bob, jim, tim, marry, luke];`

`public var usersAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(usersArr);`

Set the AC to be the data provider for the List.

`buddyList.dataProvider = usersAC;`

Define the filter function.  This function takes an object and returns true if it should be visible, false if not.

```
public function myFilterFunction(o:Object):Boolean
{
   if (o.toString() == "luke") return false;

   return true;
}
```

Then apply this function to the AC.

`usersAC.filterFunction = myFilterFunction;`

To remove the filter simply null our the filterFunction property.

`usersAC.filterFunction = null;`

Comment: Do you know if this is a flashbuilder only thing by some chance? I'm using Flash CS5.

Comment: It's a Flex thing, ya.  I saw "DataGrid" and immediately thought Flex, forgot there is a DataGrid in Flash as well.  I think you can use Flex classes in Flash but at that point you might as well be doing everything in Flex.

Comment: I'll probably just be moving my project over to Flex. This looks like just the thing i'll need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you stick the array in an ArrayCollection, you can add a filter function it to. The underlying data is un-affected.